# Most efficient way to capture OpenGL ES content of iPhone screen

Tags: opengl-es, ios, efficiency

I'd like to efficiently capture a "screenshot" of my OpenGL ES iPhone game.  I put screenshot in quotes because I really want to move the screen contents into a pixel buffer that I can eventually use to create a mov file using AVFoundation.

Currently I'm taking the screenshot with [this method from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1704/_index.html).  The resulting image is great... however capturing the image causes a small stutter in my game.  Looks like the call to `glReadPixels` causes the stutter.

**How can I capture the screen's contents more efficiently?**  Perhaps I can improve the efficiency of the call to `glReadPixels`?  Or perhaps I can populate a CMSampleBuffer or CVPixelBuffer without calling glReadPixels?

Perhaps the OpenGL ES data could be accessed directly somehow w/o having to copy the data into a buffer via `glReadPixels`.

**Edit #1**:  Perhaps a "Frame Buffer Object" could be useful?  Or "rendering directly to a texture"?

Comment: Look into pixel buffer objects. Alternatively, create a mode for your game which does not conflict with the additional load on the bus imposed by `ReadPixels`: Have the next frame rendered after be the frame that *would* have been rendered next. Your game will run slow but now you'll capture the right ones.

Answer (score 3):

Frame Buffer Object allows to create a texture where you can draw. That is Render To Texture. It is very fast (no use of CPU) and useful for mirror effects or post 2D effects. But it is a gpu object so you can access to its content with CPU; you need glReadPixels if you want to use it on CPU. the main advantage is you can set your size. So you can create a small FBO for a good framerate.

Answer (score -1):

FBO is a lot faster than glReadPixels.